# Сокращение текста, не обертывая в блок

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
    .gl {
        width: 500px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    span, .gl:before {
        display: block;
        background: red;
        content:'';
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class='gl'>Текст текст текст<span></span></div>
```

Возможно организовать таким образом, чтобы текст по центру сократить если не помещается. При условии что структура html останется прежней, то есть не обертывать лишний раз текст в блок??

Comment: Покажи т.н. "плохой" вариант с текстом. Пока не понятно про что идет речь...

Comment: Допусти задать классу `.gl { width: 50px;}` при этом как заставить текст сократить. То есть добавить троеточие в конце, так чтобы его не обертывая в еще один блок.

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;` не сокращает если родителю присвоить